# WordPress plugins_url() without http://?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, url, plugins

I want to generate the Wordpress plugin directory using this function
`plugins_url()`

However, it gives an output like this

`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins`

I want to know, is there a way to generate links like

`/[wp-installation-root]/wp-content/plugins`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
site_url()
```

or

```
bloginfo('wpurl)
```